# Como hacer un pipe en su propio shell?

Tags: shell, unix

Estoy creando un [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) UNIX y había una pregunta:

Como hacer un pipe en su propio [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)?
El comando en String esta un tabla `respP`

Esta es una idea pero no he logrado a aplicarla:

```
if(tube==1){
      //printf("\n\n\n"); // En el caso de un pipe, mas de dos comandos debe ser ejecutado
    fich = open("fichtmp",O_RDONLY,0640);// se cree un fichero 
    close(0); //se cerra el teclador  
    dup(fich); //el fichero se convierto en la entredad 0 (el input) 
    execvp(respP[0], respP); se ejecuta la commanda
    close(fich); //se cerra el fichero
}
```

Por comparacion, este es el codigo con el caso con no pipe.

```
if(tube==1){
      //printf("\n\n\n"); // En el caso de un pipe, mas de dos comandos debe ser ejecutado
    fich = open("fichtmp",O_RDONLY,0640);// se cree un fichero 
    close(0); //se cerra el teclador  
    dup(fich); //el fichero se convierto en la entredad 0 (el input) 
    execvp(respP[0], respP); se ejecuta la commanda
    close(fich); //se cerra el fichero
}
else if(output==0 && input==0){//no pipe 
    printf("truc1: Comando no encontrado");
    execvp(respP[0], respP);
}
```

Comment: Por cierto ¿para qué se usa un fichero nuevo para la entredad? Sería mejor usar [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe). Además [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) es más previsible que dup usualmente.

Comment: Si ¿darla en un tabla y hacer un `exec` sobre el?
Pero estaba buscando a crear la funcion pipe ella misma...
Y porqu utilisar el dup2? Porque es mejor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí es un ejemplo del código que ejecuta un pipe `ls /etc/ | awk '{print $9, $5}' | grep '^profile'`.

La salida de cado proceso se usa para la entrada en el próximo proceso. El primer proceso del pipe no tiene entrada (pero podría si se necesita), y la salida del último proceso se lee por el proceso principal (tu shell):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_ARGS 10 // FIXME debe ser dinámico

char* const cmds[][MAX_ARGS] = {
    { "ls", "-l", "/etc", NULL },
    { "awk", "{print $9, $5;}", NULL }, // columna $9 en ls salida es el nombre de fichero, $5 - su tamaño
    { "grep", "^profile", NULL },
};

// cerrar todos los descriptores abiertos desde `start`
void cerrar_fds(int start) {
    // Hay métodos mejores para identificar cuales ficheros son abiertos,
    // mira en http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583158/finding-open-file-descriptors-for-a-process-linux-c-code
    // pero es bastante para nuestros deberes
    int i;
    for(i = start + 1; i < 256; i++) {
            (void)close(i); // el éxito no importa
    }
}

pid_t ejec_part(char* const cmd[], int entrada, int* salida) {
    pid_t pid;
    int salidaPipe[2];
    if (pipe(salidaPipe) == -1) {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(98);
    }
    // ahora tenemos un pipe con dos lados, salidaPipe[0] es para leer
    // y salidaPipe[1] es para escribir

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { // proceso hijo
            if (entrada != -1) {
                    // dup2 es mejor que dup porque permite especificar
                    // a cual descriptor copiar el original
                    if (dup2(entrada, 0) == -1) {
                            perror("dup2");
                            exit(100);
                    }
            } else {
                    close(0);
            }
            // aquí salidaPipe[0] no se necesita
            close(salidaPipe[0]);
            // creamos una copia de salidaPipe[1] en FD == 1 (stdout)
            if (dup2(salidaPipe[1], 1) == -1) {
                    perror("dup2");
                    exit(100);
            }
            cerrar_fds(1);
            execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
            // normalmente no vamos hasta aquí
            perror("execvp");
            exit(101);
    } else if (pid < 0) { // error
            perror("fork");
            exit(99);
    } else {
            // en proceso padre salidaPipe[1] no se necesita
            close(salidaPipe[1]);
            *salida = salidaPipe[0];
            return pid;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // ls no necesita la entrada, por eso usamos -1 para la entrada
    int entradaFd = -1;
    int salidaFd = -1;
    int numCmds = sizeof(cmds) / sizeof(cmds[0]);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numCmds; i++) {
            ejec_part(cmds[i], entradaFd, &salidaFd);
            // un próximo proceso usa salidaFd del proceso anterior (el lado para leer)
            // como su entrada
            entradaFd = salidaFd;
    }
    {
            FILE* res = fdopen(entradaFd, "rb");
            int bufTam = 100;
            char* buf = malloc(bufTam);
            while(-1 != (getline(&buf, &bufTam, res))) {
                    printf("recibido de pipe: %s", buf);
            }
            fclose(res);
            free(buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tengo que confesar que español no es mi idioma nativo, soy ruso. Por eso casi estoy seguro que mi respuesta tiene erratas tantas en la lengua natural, pero el código es más o menos correcto. Si tienes preguntas or algo es oscuro, por favor digamelo.

Comment: He olvidado respuestarte! Muchas Gracias todavia estaba una respuesta muy útil!

Comment: Ok, es bueno si te ha ayudado.